# React dynamic route for webpage

Tags: reactjs, dynamic, react-router-dom

So i want a dynamic page for product details in a shop, i am getting the products and product details from an api. I would like to be able to create one page that changes depending on the product, so that it can display the content and details for whatever the user wants.

The only thing i've come across is that i need to do this:

```
<Route path="/product/:id" exact component={Page} />
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to define your route exactly as you said. then inside the Page component (product detail page), you need to get the passed param from the URL like this:

```
import {useParams} from "react-router-dom"

const {id} = useParams()
const [product, setProduct] = useState()

useEffect(() => {
const fetchedProduct = await fetchProduct(id)
setProduct(fetchedProduct)
},[]}
```

now when you go to "products/123 you would fetch a product with 123 id & set that specific product to the product state. for example, where you are displaying all the products you would make them a link that goes to the specific product page like this:

```
  products.map((product) => (
    <Link to={`/products/${product.id}`}>
      <PeoductCard product={product} />
    </Link>
  ));
```

Comment: Do you maybe have som documentation for that, i don't really follow

Comment: yes. in react-router doc here: https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useparams
if you tell me what part you can't follow I can break it down for you

Comment: I edited my response & explained a bit more. tell me if any part is unclear

Comment: How do i pass the id from the other file tho?

Comment: when you define the route, you are saying when you saw a "/product/anything"  render the Page component. so anywhere in your app, if you push to a link that has any string after the "product/" it would redirect to your Page component(product detail page). so as I said in my edited post, you would pass the id of the product as the dynamic parameter after the "products/" so it would be: to={`products/${product.id}`}

Comment: Well, i have done that, and the url changes accordingly, but how am i supposed to display the corresponding details after that?

Comment: ok, that's my first snippet. you can get that URL param inside your Page (with useParam hook) & show the corresponding product based on it (for example you pass it to your fetch function as I showed). so if you push to "product/123" you would fetch the product with id "123" and set that response data to the product state, so it would be the product with the id of "123" & you would render that, if you push to "product/456" you would fetch the product with "456" id & would render that. so just add the first snippet to your Page component & use the id to fetch the relevant product